# Add customized Bokeh JS

Tags: javascript, bokeh, bokehjs

I'm new to Bokeh Server and intrigued how Bokeh is able to get the  `static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js` file eventhough this folder doesn't exist.

I'm trying to use a customised version of bokeh-widget js. I've added the JS file in `/myapp/static/js/bokeh-widgets.2.1.1.js` but when i see the network call and breakpoints, Bokeh is using minified version of JS `static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js` instead of `/myapp/static/js/bokeh-widgets.2.1.1.js`

Bokeh server is using it's own JS `static/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js` instead of JS file which I've downloaded in the `/myapp/static/js/bokeh-widgets.2.1.1.js` file. [image]

Index.html
[image]

Comment: @philippjfr any help pls ?